# Unable to Create Views in Grails 2.2 for Domain with enum

Tags: grails, enums

I am using Grails 2.2.0 (Groovy 2), Java 1.7 on window pc.
I have a simple test Grails project, with only three domain classes.

I am having a problem creating a view for domain with enum.

Here is my code:

```
package com.testapp

class Visit {

    enum States { ACCEPTED, DECLINED, COMPLETED, IGNORED }
    States state = States.ACCEPTED

    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

When I run: generate-all com.testapp.Visit or generate-views com.testapp.VisitType
It's doesn't create any views and give the following error on the console,

```
| Error Error executing script GenerateViews: (class: com/testapp/VisitType$States, method: getGormPersistentEntity signature: ()Lorg/grails/datastore/mapping/model/PersistentEntity;) Incompatible type for getting or setting field (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I am bit lost here, I am new to grails. Please could you point me in the right direction, where I am going wrong? Also could you know how I can see Stacktrace in GGTS?

Many thanks
ish

Answer (score 0):

```
public Enum State {

    ACCEPTED, DECLINED, COMPLETED, IGNORED 
}

public class Visit {

    State state = State.ACCEPTED

    String name
}
```